# dynamically Add TextField With Tag On button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want To add textfield dynamically with tag so that it can give unique value everytime. And than add those values and want to show on label.... when i click button one textfield add n give the value , and that value Add to the previous value...

Value adding Successfully... But when i edit anything or change or give another value such as (10 instead of 12) the loop will run again because of this line

```
[Txt_New_Estimated addTarget:self action:@selector(C6Loop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

2nd problem is that when i add new textfield then previous textfield did not modified and do not add in rest of textfields... before adding new textfield it works properly but when edit anything loop will run again....
i want to overCome this problem, so please check this code and give some possible solution...
i am sending my code here
Please check this code...

Thank You...

Comment: I have few questions about the problem. When do you add textfields, are all of them added before any user action or they are added with user interaction? You said "Value adding Successfully.....But when i edit anything or change or give another value such as (10 instead of 12) the loop will run again because of this line " what is the exact problem here? Also it will be helpful if you clarify 2nd problem so that we can suggest any solution.

Comment: they are added with user interaction , means 4 textfield by default showing with different different name an the last textfiled with on add button , when the user click on add buttons the new text filed add and when the user give value like 13 it will add rest of the textfield by [Txt_New_Estimated addTarget:self action:@selector(C6Loop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
....  which i write code on C6loop method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the target - action with this method:

```
- (void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

Comment: they are added with user interaction , means 4 textfield by default showing with different different name an the last textfiled with on add button , when the user click on add buttons the new text filed add and when the user give value like 13 it will add rest of the textfield by [Txt_New_Estimated addTarget:self action:@selector(C6Loop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
....  which i write code on C6loop methodcomments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss) Please give me ur email so that i can show You my code here i am unable to write bcoz indent 4 space